# google tells me that my app crashes on (only) Google Pixel 2 (virtuel)

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception

I'm trying to publish my app in google play console.
But it tells me that it crashes on Google Pixel 2 (virtuel) (works on the 9 others) with 2 errors (very similar)

```
Google Pixel 2 (virtuel) 1080x1920 Android 12 (SDK 31) - x86_64 en_US
```

**Error**:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void androidx.activity.result.ActivityResultLauncher.launch(java.lang.Object)' on a null object reference
```

**Detail**:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-2
Process: xxxxxxxx, PID: 8724
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void androidx.activity.result.ActivityResultLauncher.launch(java.lang.Object)' on a null object reference
    at xxxxxxxx.models.StockInputDialog.lambda$init$9$xxxxxxxx-models-StockInputDialog(StockInputDialog.java:417)
    at xxxxxxxx.models.StockInputDialog$$ExternalSyntheticLambda9.onClick(Unknown Source:2)
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:7441)
    at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:7418)
    at android.view.View.access$3700(View.java:835)
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:28676)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at androidx.test.espresso.base.Interrogator.loopAndInterrogate(Interrogator.java:10)
    at androidx.test.espresso.base.UiControllerImpl.loopUntil(UiControllerImpl.java:7)
    at androidx.test.espresso.base.UiControllerImpl.loopUntil(UiControllerImpl.java:1)
    at androidx.test.espresso.base.UiControllerImpl.injectMotionEvent(UiControllerImpl.java:5)
    at androidx.test.espresso.action.MotionEvents.sendUp(MotionEvents.java:6)
    at androidx.test.espresso.action.MotionEvents.sendUp(MotionEvents.java:1)
    at androidx.test.espresso.action.Tap.sendSingleTap(Tap.java:5)
    at androidx.test.espresso.action.Tap.-$$Nest$smsendSingleTap(Unknown Source:0)
    at androidx.test.espresso.action.Tap$1.sendTap(Tap.java:1)
    at androidx.test.espresso.action.GeneralClickAction.perform(GeneralClickAction.java:4)
    at androidx.test.espresso.ViewInteraction$SingleExecutionViewAction.perform(ViewInteraction.java:2)
    at androidx.test.espresso.ViewInteraction.doPerform(ViewInteraction.java:21)
    at androidx.test.espresso.ViewInteraction.-$$Nest$mdoPerform(Unknown Source:0)
    at androidx.test.espresso.ViewInteraction$1.call(ViewInteraction.java:6)
    at androidx.test.espresso.ViewInteraction$1.call(ViewInteraction.java:1)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:201)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:288)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7839)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:548)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1003)
```

My code is explained (and the reason why) [startActivityForResult migration, call registerForActivityResult outside activity](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73072829/13463349), and simplified to the maximum:

```
public class StockActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements DialogCloseListener {
    private ActivityResultLauncher<Intent> stockGalleryActivityResultLauncher;
    private ActivityResultLauncher<Intent> stockCameraActivityResultLauncher;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        stockCameraActivityResultLauncher = registerForActivityResult(new ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult(),
                result -> {
                    // code
                });
        stockGalleryActivityResultLauncher = registerForActivityResult(new ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult(),
                result -> {
                    // code
                });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
        if (id == R.id.action_add) {
            mStockInputDialog = new StockInputDialog(this, stockCameraActivityResultLauncher,   stockGalleryActivityResultLauncher,);
            return true;
        } else {
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }
}

public class StockInputDialog {
    private final Context mContext;
    private AlertDialog mInputDialog;
    private ActivityResultLauncher<Intent> stockCameraActivityResultLauncher;
    private ActivityResultLauncher<Intent> stockGalleryActivityResultLauncher;

    public StockInputDialog(Context context, ActivityResultLauncher<Intent> pStockCameraActivityResultLaunchera, ActivityResultLauncher<Intent> pStockGalleryActivityResultLauncher) {
        mContext = context;
        stockCameraActivityResultLauncher = pStockCameraActivityResultLaunchera;
        stockGalleryActivityResultLauncher = pStockGalleryActivityResultLauncher;
        LayoutInflater li = LayoutInflater.from(this.mContext);
        mPromptsView = li.inflate(R.layout.text_input_stock, null);
        final AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this.mContext);
        alertDialogBuilder.setView(mPromptsView);

        final ImageButton imgButtonCam = mPromptsView.findViewById(R.id.addCam);
        final ImageButton imgButtonGal = mPromptsView.findViewById(R.id.addGal);

        imgButtonCam.setOnClickListener(view -> {
            Uri uri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(mContext, "fr.foo.bar.provider",
                    new Product(Consts.TEMP_NUM).getIMGPathCacheFile(mContext));
            Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, uri);
            stockCameraActivityResultLauncher.launch(intent); <= ERROR
        });

        imgButtonGal.setOnClickListener(view -> {
            stockGalleryActivityResultLauncher.launch(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI)) <= ERROR
        });
    }
}
```

The 2 errors correspond to the 2 `launch()`

What I don't understand is that I'm using this same principle elsewhere in the application without an error being raised.

Comment: Replace `ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult()` with `ActivityResultContracts.TakePicture()` and `stockCameraActivityResultLauncher.launch(intent)` with `stockCameraActivityResultLauncher.launch(uri)`. no need for `intent` in this case.

Comment: @Abdo21
Let's assume, although that doesn't explain why it works fine elsewhere in the application without errors.
However, if I change to TakePicture(), I also have to change the other to GetContent( ) since I get an error on each. But unfortunately, the presentation of the image selection is not the same, and I prefer the other one.
Still, I'm going to adapt this, and submit to google to see if it works.
Thanks.

Comment: It's crashing because either `stockGalleryActivityResultLauncher` or `stockCameraActivityResultLauncher` is *null* in your `StockInputDialog` at the moment those buttons are clicked, an you can't call `launch` on *null*. I can't see anything wrong with the code you've posted (`registerForActivityResult` doesn't return *null* according to the docs) so I'm guessing there's a bug that's not present in this simplified version. Your error's happening on *line 417* of that class so that's a fair bit of code that's missing! Might be worth creating your own emulator for API 31 and debugging it

Comment: If this feature is not the main feature in your App, you can check for nullability instead of craching maybe like this : `if(stockCameraActivityResultLauncher != null) stockCameraActivityResultLauncher.launch() else Toast.makeText("sorry this feature is not available on your device")`

Comment: You can watch the video on Google of what actions it took to make it crash then try doing those same steps in an emulator to replicate it locally. The steps it takes are semi random so it may pass again later even if there is still a bug, or may fail on a totally different device and Android version

Comment: @cactustictacs I understand what you mean, but the problem is that I don't have the crash, even with avd Pixel 2 API 31. I saw that I'm not the only one who get google crash signaling about this pixel 2.

Comment: To clarify, the videos I was referring to are from the pre-launch app tests that Google runs and which show up in your developer console for each release. There are no videos for production crashes.

Comment: @Abdo21 same crash with TakePicture() and GetContent(). I'm now sending a version with this workarround (test if null). Wait & See.

Comment: @TylerV didn't find any video, only screenshots. May be because I'm still in phase "internal tests"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No more crashes when testing the "nullity" of the launchers (@Abdo21 2nd answer).

```
    imgButtonCam.setOnClickListener(view -> {
        Uri uri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(mContext, "fr.novazur.donteat.provider",
                new Product(Consts.TEMP_NUM).getIMGPathCacheFile(mContext));
        if (stockCameraActivityResultLauncher != null)
            stockCameraActivityResultLauncher.launch(uri);
        else
            Toast.makeText(mContext, R.string.featureAbsent, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    });
    imgButtonGal.setOnClickListener(view -> {
        if (stockGalleryActivityResultLauncher != null)
            stockGalleryActivityResultLauncher.launch("image/*");
        else
            Toast.makeText(mContext, R.string.featureAbsent, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    });
```

That's what I should have done from the start. I'm a little sorry for not having thought of it, it's so obvious. I guess it's related to the creation of the AlertDialog which should not allow immediate access to the launchers. What I don't understand in this case is why only the Pixel 2 crashes, but problem seems to be solved for the moment. Thanks all.